# Set ListView onItemClick() to only proceed when item pressed down, not item released

Tags: android, listview, action, motionevent

Im stuck. I have a listView item that when pressed calls an other activity. But the activity is being called twice. Once when the list item is pressed and once when it is released.

I looked for examples for filtering the Motion event on a listView item but couldn't find any. I tried to manually add `MotionEvent event` to the `onItemClick()` arguments, but that failed.

Can anyone provide an example?

Current Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        generateListView();
}


public void generateListView(final JSONArray relevantGames, ArrayList listViewItems, String teamName) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listViewItems);
        final ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.gameList);
        lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        lv.setAdapter(adapterList);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                
                 //Want To Put a motion down check
                   selectedGame = relevantGames.getJSONObject(position);
                  
                 //Start new intent with putExtra(selectedGame)
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: A click only fires upon `ACTION_UP`, so `onItemClick()` will only run once for each down-up sequence. If you have an `Activity` starting twice, it's unlikely to be due to the `OnItemClickListener` executing more than it should. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Is the way to add a log statement after setting the onItemClickListener but before onItemClick()? Android studio won't let me complie if I put log.i() in that space

Comment: If you want to log clicks, it would go inside of the `onItemClick()` method.

Comment: Yeah, I think i have a totally different problem. After logging clicks I see its only getting clicked 1 once. But onCreate() is still being called twice in my other activity. So I think its trying to start, dies, then restarts. Dont know why

Comment: Are you doing a `setRequestedOrientation()` call in that second `Activity`, too? That might cause it to recreate.

Comment: @MikeM. Yes I am. Im doing ```SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE``` The activity that I am coming from is set to ```SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT```. Would that mess it up?

Comment: I'm not sure what's messing up on your end, exactly, but yeah, if an `Activity` starts out at its very beginning in one orientation, and then requests a different orientation in its `onCreate()` method, that can cause the `Activity` to be recreated, which means that its `onCreate()` method will run once more. That's not unexpected; that's just how Android handles configuration changes, by default.

Comment: @MikeM. Hmm ok. Im still new to android development. I actually put my ```setRequestOrientation``` in an ```onWindowFocusedChange()``` call back. Set it up like that because I saw an example of some else putting it there. From what your saying it sounds like I should move it to onStart or onResume()

Comment: Well, it's not really a matter of which lifecycle method you have it in; it's that you're doing it at all. I'd just assumed it was in `onCreate()`, but even if you move it to either of those other methods, it'll still have the same effect. It'll just happen a little later, because those methods both run pretty soon after `onCreate()`. This is normal Android behavior, btw, so your overall design should be able to handle configuration changes at any time, because your `Activity` might be recreated for any number of other reasons, too.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the info. Very helpful. I think I got it working for the most part. Just like you said, mostly a problem with my overall design, not so much android bugs.